# general solution of $x\frac{dy}{dx}-4y=x^6e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have a question about the following example in Zill and Wright's textbook:

> **Example** $\quad$ Solve $x\frac{dy}{dx}-4y=x^6e^x.$

This is a simple example to illustrate how to find general solution of a linear first-order differential equation (DE):

> **Solution** $\quad$ By dividing by $x$ we get the standard form
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{4}{x}y=x^5e^x.$$
>   Let $P(x)\triangleq-4/x$ and $f(x)\triangleq x^5e^x$.  Note that $P$ and $f$ are continuous on $(0, \infty)$, so the general solution on $(0, \infty)$ is $y=y_c+y_p,$ where $y_c=ce^{-\int P(x)dx}$ is the general solution to the homogeneneous DE, and $$y_p=e^{-\int P(x)dx}\int e^{\int P(x)dx}f(x)dx$$
>   is a particular solution to the non-homogeneous DE.
>
> Now, note that $e^{-\int P(x)dx}=e^{\int 4/xdx}=x^{4}$ on $(0, \infty)$. So $y_c=cx^4$ and a particular solution is $y_p=x^{4}\int xe^xdx=x^4(x-1)e^x.$ Hence the general solution is $y=cx^4+x^4(x-1)e^x$ on $(0, \infty)$.

---

**My question:** Isn't $y=cx^4+x^4(x-1)e^x$ the general solution on the entire real line as well?

We're restricted to $(0, \infty)$ to make $P$ continuous.  The above argument also holds on $(-\infty, 0)$.  However, $P$ isn't in the original problem.  It's an intermediate term we invented to solve the DE, and as a result we exclude $\{0\}$ from the real line.

Looking at the original DE, any solution $y$ must be $0$ when $x=0.$ And $y=cx^4+x^4(x-1)e^x$ clearly satisfies this.  So is there any problem to say that it is *the* general solution of the original DE on the entire real line?  Did I miss something?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the singular point at 0, the solution on each side doesn't necessarily have to "match up". That means $c$ can take on different values for positive and negative numbers, and the general solution is
$$
y = \begin{cases}c_1 x^4 + x^4(x-1)e^x & x < 0 \\ c_2x^4 + x^4(x-1)e^x & x\ge 0\end{cases}
$$
or equivalently
$$
y = b_1 x^4 + b_2 x^3|x| + x^4(x-1)e^x
$$
for some constants $b_1$ and $b_2$.

Comment: A singular point is any point where one of the coefficient functions of the DE in standard form has a singularity. In this case, $4/x$ has a singularity at $0$.

Comment: You mean to say original DE is not continuous at x=0. Am i right?

Comment: Indeed.  I thought about this question some more.  So, for instance, the initial value problem (IVP), $x \frac{dy}{dx}-4y=x^6e^x, y(1)=1$, has a unique solution only on $(0, \infty)$ or $[0, \infty)$, but not on the entire real line?  In other words, $c_2=1$ is uniquely defined, but $c_1$ can take any value.  For example, together with either $c_1=3$ or $c_1=-2$, we have a legitimate solution on $(-\infty, \infty)$ to the IVP.  And each solution is continuously differentiable on $(-\infty, \infty)$.